# Remove invalid characters from domain

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this regular expression:

```
/^(((?!\-))(xn\-\-)?[a-z0-9\-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn\-\-)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9\-]{1,30})\.[a-z]{2,}$/
```

and this domain value: `domain!@#$test:ing.com`

I want to remove all this unsupported characters, and I tried this:

```
string.replace(/^(((?!\-))(xn\-\-)?[a-z0-9\-_]{0,61}[a-z0-9]{1,1}\.)*(xn\-\-)?([a-z0-9\-]{1,61}|[a-z0-9\-]{1,30})\.[a-z]{2,}$/,'');
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas why?

I tried different codes, and I expect that this code will remove unsupported characters from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression in your question is meant to *validate* domain names. You can cannot use it to replace characters inside a string. You'll have to create a new regular expression with the undesired characters.

Based on your regex, it will probably be something like:

```
string.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-_\.]/g, "")
```

`^` negates what's inside the brackets...

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing but exclude these characters? This code doesn't work: `string.replace(/[~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|"':;?,/><,/g,''));`

Comment: You have to escape `]` inside your regular expression, otherwise the engine will try to interpret it as the closing bracket: `string.replace(/[~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}[\]|"':;?,/><,]/g,'')`.

Comment: That's almost perefect but ```\``` character doesn't work :/

Comment: It's because it's not included yet. You're merely escaping `-` (which inside `[..]` defines a range). Just add it to the expression (escape it with another ```\```): `string.replace(/[~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}[\]|"':;?,/><,\\]/g,'')`

Comment: It still doesn't replace ```\```

Comment: On what string are you testing? it works for me...

Comment: I had to check wrong. It's working fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have question for that. I want to allow `-` inside string, but not allow it at the end. So for example want to replace `test-.com` to `test.com`. I tried modifing this code adding `[-]$`, so the code looks like that: `string..replace(/[~!@#$%^&`*()_\+={}[\]|"':;?,/><,\\][-]$/g,'')`. But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @test please create a new question with `regex` tag and a detailed description of what you tried and want to achieve. You'll get an answer in no time. Comments are aweful when it comes to formatting...